# WordPress - is there a standalone gallery plugin (not in gutenberg, but at sidebar of post admin)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

im looking for some simple free thingy to select post photos, but i dont want it to be part ogf main content, like it would be in gutenberg. I like the way ACF Pro has it, but for this one unctionality, paying its price yearly is nonsense. id like something to work in post admin as a block in post properties sidebar, not inside editor

Comment: Your question description is a bit confusing but you can try https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-lightbox/ plugin and it has many settings to disable things that you don't want to use from the plugin.

Comment: well, im talking about admin side, im doing the front side myself (custom theme from scratch, vue, cached templates etc), but i intend to display the gallery not in main content area, but in sidebar, separated. And therefore, also in admin, i would like to have it separated from main editor area to not make it too confusing for client. For the rest i use ACF free version, to set things like each office name, phone, hours, ... but the gallery plugin in ACF is only on PRO version, which is too damn hight (few hundreds yearly, im doing a lowcost web for nonprofit organization).